# SQL select from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue selecting from a subquery with this small demo data for example:

```
ID          CLASS_ID               PROP          STATUS        ROW     SELECTED    STEP
12345679    1312            0         21           3       07-FEB-14    1
12345679    1312            0         21           1       26-FEB-14    -1
```

I want to get all the information (each column), the sql below works ok

```
SELECT ID,CLASS_ID,min(SELECTED) FROM ( SELECT... ) GROUP BY ID,CLASS_ID

ID          CLASS_ID             SELECTED   
12345679    1312                07-FEB-14
```

But if I want other columns I must add them to the group statement else I get "not a group statement" thus making it obsolete, any ideas?

Comment: You can use any aggregation function like MAX, MIN, SUM etc. for those fields.

Comment: are you trying to get the entire row of data for where the `SELECTED` column is the minimum when grouped by `ID, CLASS_ID` ?

Comment: Put the min(selected) part into another subquery.

Comment: In the subquery i quoted I have at least 5 subqueries, it`s actually a view...the date comes from 3 unions...its hell my friend

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the analytic function `row_number()`:

```
select ID, CLASS_ID, PROP, STATUS, ROW, SELECTED  
from (select s.*, row_number() over (partition by id, class_id
                                     order by selected desc) as seqnum
      from (<subquery>) s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you want to get the minimum of `selected` column based on group by `ID` and `class_id` with all other columns then you can use `MIN() over partitioned by` function -

```
SELECT ID,
       CLASS_ID,
       min(SELECTED) over (partition by ID,CLASS_ID order by 1) , 
       col1 ...
FROM ( SELECT... )
```

Comment: Thank you too, it is the first time I have used 'over' :)